# Constructing a smooth injective path between two points in a connected open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology, euclidean-geometry

By the connectedness, there is a continuous path between two points x and y, and by compactness I can find a finite open covering discs of this path, then I can easily construct a smooth function in the union of these discs. But how to deal with the injectivity ?Construct a smooth injective ( the path do not cross itself)path?

Comment: By connected you mean path connected, yes?

Comment: @G. Chiusole: Yes, in $\mathbb{R}^2$ an open set, connectedness and path connectedness are equivalent.

Comment: How familiar are you with Riemannian geometry? If you are, construct a complete Riemannian metric on your domain and take shortest geodesic connecting the given pair of points.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan  I haven’t studied Riemannian geometry.  I am studying differential geometry at the undergraduate level.  Does this construction satisfy smoothness and injectivity?  The existence is enough for me ( better someone can give a elementary construction ).

Comment: @user725757: Yes, it will be $C^\infty$-smooth and injective.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan: I’ll refer to this. Thank you.